# rails has_one through form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

administrator.rb:

```
class Administrator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :administrator_role, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :role, through: :administrator_role
end
```

role.rb:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :administrator_roles
    has_many :administrators, through: :administrator_roles
end
```

administrator_role.rb:

```
class AdministratorRole < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :administrator
    belongs_to :role
end
```

in view for "new" action administrator_controller:

```
<%= form_for @administrator do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @administrator %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :role_id, "Роль:" %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:role_id, @roles, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
...
  <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
```

administrator_controller.rb:

```
class AdministratorsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @administrator = Administrator.new
    @roles = Role.all
  end

  def create
    @administrator = Administrator.new(administrators_params)
    if @administrator.save
      flash[:success] = "Account registered!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

...
  private

  def administrators_params
    params.require(:administrator).permit(:login, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_id)
  end
end
```

when you open the page get the error:

```
undefined method `role_id' for #<Administrator:0x007f6ffc859b48>
Did you mean?  role
```

How to fix it? if I put in place role_id a role, when you create administrator will get the error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Role(#69964494936160) expected, got String(#12025960)):
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to rewrite the form as below:

```
<%= form_for @administrator do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @administrator %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.fields_for :role do |role_form| %
      <%= role_form.label :role_id, "Роль:" %>
      <%= role_form.select(:id, @roles.map { |role| [role.name, role.id] }) %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
...
  <%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
```

You also need to add 1 line which enables the nested form logic as:

```
class Administrator < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :administrator_role, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :role, through: :administrator_role
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :role
end
```

And also change the controller like:

```
class AdministratorsController < ApplicationController

  #....

  private

  def administrators_params
    params.require(:administrator).permit(
      :login, :password,
      :password_confirmation,
      role_attributes: [ :id ]
    )
  end
end
```

When you are using `has_one` association, you get the below method, but not `association_id=`, and that is what error is saying.

```
association(force_reload = false)
association=(associate)
build_association(attributes = {})
create_association(attributes = {})
create_association!(attributes = {})
```